# Cannot access mysql server with phpMyAdmin

Tags: php, mariadb, wamp

I have recently installed the last version of WAMP, but I have a problem accessing the MySQL (MariaDB) Server.  I can access the server with MariaDB Console. Therefore, I am sure password and username are correct, and the server is running.

```
WAMP: 3.2.2
Apache: 2.4.41
PHP: 7.4.0
MariaDB: 10.4.10
phpMyAdmin: 5.0.2
```

When I access with phpMyAdmin webpage:

[image]

I also tried to access with a simple test script:

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";

try {
  $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=myDB", $username, $password);
  // set the PDO error mode to exception
  $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
  echo "Connected successfully";
} catch(PDOException $e) {
  echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();
}
?>
```

When running in browser I got similar error:

[image]

Running the same script from the command line, works:

[image]

I tried to change `$servername = "127.0.0.1";` and got the same result.

I also tried to change the password of the root user from MariaDB console, with the command:

```
  FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
  ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'MyNewPass';
```

The password changed, I've updated the test script `$password = "MyNewPass";`, and still the same result.

WAMP, right click, Tools-> Test port 3306. Also gives the expected result:

```
***** Test which uses port 3306 *****

===== Tested by command netstat filtered on port 3306 =====


Test for TCP
Your port 3306 is used by a processus with PID = 8660
The processus of PID 8660 is 'mysqld.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 8660 for 'mysqld.exe' is 'wampmariadb64'
This service is from Wampserver - It is correct

Test for TCPv6
Your port 3306 is used by a processus with PID = 8660
The processus of PID 8660 is 'mysqld.exe' Session: Services
The service of PID 8660 for 'mysqld.exe' is 'wampmariadb64'
This service is from Wampserver - It is correct
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: could it be some protection like SELinux is blocking your Apache to access the database? edit: seems you're on Windows

Comment: Try change the address to `127.0.0.1/testConnection.php`? Sometimes I will encounter `localhost` being parsed into ipv6 format `::1` and then pma cannot interpret it and cause an error.

Comment: I've tried, and got the same error

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you should configure phpMyAdmin from wamp tools and you should enter from your local ip address use `ipconfig` console than php script should work.

Comment: I've tried to change to local ip address, and got the same result. For some reason apache cannot connect to mysql server